# redirecting boost bind

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

Is the following conversion possible? I've tried boost::lambda and just a plain bind, but I'm struggling to make the conversion in-place without a special helper class that would process foo and invoke bar.

```
struct Foo {}; // untouchable
struct Bar {}; // untouchable

// my code
Bar ConvertFooToBar(const Foo& foo) { ... }

void ProcessBar(const Bar& bar) { ... }

boost::function<void (const Foo&)> f = 
 boost::bind(&ProcessBar, ?);

f(Foo()); // ProcessBar is invoked with a converted Bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing functional composition. So you have to compose your `bind`s. You need `ProcessBar(ConvertFooToBar(...))` to happen. So you have to actually do that.

```
boost::function<void (const Foo&)> f = 
 boost::bind(&ProcessBar, boost::bind(ConvertFooToBar, _1));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that composing with `bind` can be tricky if you don't want all placeholders to be replaced in the top-level expression and need to use `boost::protect`.